# Center a round (circle) button in a gird

Tags: wpf, button, grid, centering

I have a round (circle) button that looks like this:

[image]

It is made of an `Ellipse` like that (simplified):

```
<Ellipse Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

Complete style of the button:

```
<Style x:Key="StatusButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource StatusButtonBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource StatusButtonForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="StatusButtonCircle" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="{StaticResource StatusButtonBackground}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="StatusButtonCircleHighlight" Margin="10" Stroke="{StaticResource StatusButtonHighlight}" StrokeThickness="5" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="StatusButtonCircle" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource StatusButtonDisabledForeground}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="StatusButtonCircleHighlight" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource StatusButtonDisabledHighlight}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Used in the grid:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource StatusButton}"
        Margin="50" Grid.Column="2" />
```

How can I make it, that the circle is in the center of the grid?

---

Trying to center the grid in the style

So i changed the grid in style to this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Ellipse x:Name="StatusButtonCircle" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="{StaticResource StatusButtonBackground}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        <Ellipse x:Name="StatusButtonCircleHighlight" Margin="10" Stroke="{StaticResource StatusButtonHighlight}" StrokeThickness="5" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </Grid>
    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

now it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you show more XAML such as the `StatusButton` Style?

Comment: We need to see the `Style` because if you are using `StackPanel` then it will take the least amount of space.

Comment: Try placing the two `Ellipses` inside of a container, like another `Grid`, and set the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` on that to "Center"

Comment: @Matt L.: I edited my post and tried your solution. Did I understand it right? Now the circle got to the center but is very small.

Comment: Not quite, I meant `<Grid><Grid Centered><Ellipses/></Grid><Content/></Grid>`

Comment: edited my post, still looks the same

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add margin as such..

```
<Grid Margin="0,50,0,0">
    <Ellipse x:Name="StatusButtonCircle" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="{StaticResource StatusButtonBackground}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    <Ellipse x:Name="StatusButtonCircleHighlight" Margin="10" Stroke="{StaticResource StatusButtonHighlight}" StrokeThickness="5" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</Grid>
```

and modify the top margin as per appropriate...

Comment: this does work `<Grid Margin="25,0,0,0">`, but it doesn't feel right. It is "manually" positioned in the center. If I change the margin of the button `Margin="50"` it is not in the center anymore.